# How to dynamically generate SVG image from java code in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am stuck at one point where I have to display a SVG image on the springboot webpage, which is generated from Graphviz code in Java.
Any help is highly appreciated.

This is my controller class.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/e2emap", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getE2E_WebPage(Model model
            @RequestParam(name = Query_refresh_param, required = false) String refreshInterval) throws IOException {
        final var graph = graphGenerator.createGraph();
        final String graphString = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(graph);

        model.addAttribute("graphVariable", graphString);
        model.addAttribute("graph", graph);

        return "Dynamic";
```

Here is the Dynamic.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
 <link href="../static/css/styles.css" data-th-href="@{/css/styles.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
 <title>SRE End-2-End flow</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="title"><a class="a-sre-e2e" >SRE End-2-End Flow</a></div>
 <meta http-equiv= "refresh" content = "15 " />
 <p>
 <form action="/e2emap" method="get">
 <span class="variable-title">Target Environment</span>
 <select class="variable-combobox-values" name="target_env" id="target_env" onchange="submit()"> 
 <option th:each="env : ${environments}" th:text="${env}" th:selected="${env}==${targetEnv}">sample-env</option>
   </select>
  </form>
  <h1 th:text="${targetEnv}">bla-bla</h1>
  <span>
  <img th:src="@{'data:graph/svg;base64' + ${graph}}"> </img> Image
  </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Some points to specify:
method createGraph() is the main method that uses graphviz to generate the graph and returns the graph in byteArray[] form.

The html has a drop down list to select different values. On-click, it should display the graph, which is not happening at the moment.

Comment: It seems you should be doing + ${graphVariable}

Comment: You may need a comma after base64

Comment: Is `graph` the actual SVG as a String? If so, you could just include the SVG itself without using an `img` tag.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I tried to insert the actual svg string, but it is not displayed as an image, instead it is displayed as a text string. That's where I am stuck.

Comment: Have you checked in the browser how the generated HTML looks like? Did you use `[(...)]` to insert it?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe no, i am storing the text file in a variable and trying to insert it using this fragment:  ``` <span th:text="${graphVariable}"> ```

Comment: Try with `th:utext` instead of `th:text`